# F is a field that contains 4 elements {0,1,a,b} , given ab=1, prove that a^2 = b

Tags: axioms, formal-proofs

How do I prove that a^2 = b using the field axioms of closure, associativity, commutativity, multiplicative and additive identities, negatives and reciprocals, and distributivity?

My current attempt is:

a = a + 0 (additive identity)

a = a + (-b + b) (existence of negatives)

a * a = a * a + a*(-b) + a*(b) (distributivity of multiplication)

This is where I get stuck even if I sub in ab=1, there is still the a*a on the right side of the equation and no b. Does anyone see where I went wrong or an alternative way to begin this question?

Comment: $a^2$ is some element of the field. If $a^2=0$, then $0=a^2b=a(ab)=a$. If $a^2=1$, then $a=b$. If $a^2=a$, then $a=1$. So, we can only have $a^2=b$.

Comment: See the answer below, or @user85667 's comment, and take in how the proof goes. The technique of process of elimination is something that will likely come up again and again in your study of finite mathematics. [And as far as what you tried here, you need to be careful, it is a priori possible that a nonzero element $a \in F$ is its own negative, i.e., $a=-a$ even though $a \not = 0$. And in fact, in a field of $4$  elements [in fact a field of $2^k$ elements for any positive integer $k$], it is **always** true that $a=-a$ for *all* elements in $F$!

Comment: Another option can be to show. or use, that finite fields of the same size are isomorphic, and show that in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)=\{0,1,x,x+1\}$ we have $x^2=x+1$ and $(x+1)^2=x$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1. First, note that $a^2 \not = 1$, because $ab = 1$ and as $a \not = b$, it follows that $a^2 \not = ab$.
2. Next, $a^2 \not = a$, because $a \times 1 = a$.
3. Finally, $a^2 \not = 0$, because $F$ is a field and $a$ is a nonzero element.

What do you have left?

Comment: I see you proof using elimination, thanks for the help. Could I use the same method for this question where they ask if a and b are elements in a field, proof that if a * b = 0, a = 0 or b = 0

Comment: RE your question in the comment, use the fact every nonzero element in $F$ has a multiplicative inverse, and a nonzero element $a$ cannot have a multiplicative inverse if $ab=0$ for some nonzero $b$. Likewise, neither can a nonzero element $b$ have a multiplicative inverse if $ab=0$ for some nonzero $a$. Not a proof by elimination true. Proof by elimination is but one tool in your tool box though.

Comment: would your explanation for my 2nd qn change if the field was an infinite field and a and b are just two elements within it? Also, the question does not state if a and b are non zero.

Comment: If $F=\{0,1,a,b\}$ i.e., $4$ elements, then $a$ and $b$ are necessarily nonzero. And yes my proof relies on $F$ having order $4$.